# Edittext crash issue on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Whenever I tap again on my editext it crashes and displays this error message.
For example: I already type something on the editext then when I tap the editext again this is the crash message.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.homeownersportal.dmci_mobile_app_android, PID: 1922
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.getHotspotX(Editor.java:6465)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updateDrawable(Editor.java:5345)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.setDrawables(Editor.java:5330)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.<init>(Editor.java:5308)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.<init>(Editor.java:5238)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.<init>(Editor.java:6397)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:7194)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:7170)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:2678)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:12054)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14376)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:729)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1922)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4051)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.testfairy.i.c.y.dispatchTouchEvent(SourceFile:16)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:687)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14644)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6522)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6309)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5766)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5774)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5766)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5774)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8906)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8767)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8720)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9042)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:194)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Here's the header layout in the navigation drawer where the edittext is located.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_drawer_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_image_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_45sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_user_profile_placeholder" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_navigation_back_arrow"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_back_arrow_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_full_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Juan Dela Cruz"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_heavy"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_image_container" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_resident_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resident Owner"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_heavy"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_full_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_residence"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_resident_type" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_switch"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/drawable_switch_unit_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_residence"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_residence"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_residence" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_background"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_navigation_search"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_navigation_search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:hint="@string/search_dmci_communities"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_heavy"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_residence" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kindly help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Your logcat said: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference`.
You need to check out why it occurs **null reference** from the drawable.
Maybe you have not assign any reference to it yet before using it.

Comment: I haven't set anything regarding on getIntrinsicWidth in my java

Comment: Or maybe you can post some snippet code relative with the `EditText`, so we may find out problem together.

Comment: does your problem still occurs when you remove `drawableEnd` or `drawableRight` (or even both)?